# See all changes in one place, like GitHub does?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

*First of all, I am not sure if StackOverflow is the place to ask this (I already considered Programmers StackExchange, but that also seemed a bit off). If this is not the right place, please help me move the question or suggest where I can ask it instead.*

If you're using TFS, is there an effective way to do reviews like GitHub offers? In GitHub, you typically submit a pull request. This pull request then lets you see *all the changes* made in that whole pull request, making it easy for you to review (because you can just keep scrolling down).

Can the same be done in Visual Studio with TFS, or do I really have to see the changes for every file that has been changed manually? It just seems crazy.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't a single overview. You do have the code request feature (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/code/get-code-reviewed-vs) but that still shows a list of files. But you do know that you can use Git with Pull Requests and everything wen using TFS?

Comment: Create that as an answer, and I'll mark it as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't a single overview. You do have the [code request feature](http://visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/code/get-code-reviewed-vs) but that still shows a list of files.

Instead of using TFVC with Code Reviews, you can also [use Git as the version control system.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/code/share-your-code-in-git-vs) You can then use regular pull requests in the same way you would use GitHub.